# How to provide unique user_id in profile factory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-factory

since this "new" update came in laravel (laravel 8) I am struggling with factories. I need help on how to provide unique id from the User model to user_id column in profile factory. In my User model I have a relationship with profile:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

In profile model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And now I have to provide data to profile factory:

```
 return [
        'user_id' => ,
        'image' => 'image',
        'bio' => $this->faker->sentence,
...
```

Comment: how about using `$this->faker->unique()->randomDigitNotNull;`

Comment: cant use random digit because it may cause an error when 2 users have the same ID :) It is a foreign ID and must be unique. I was wondering if there is way to make profile when the user is made with factory :)

Answer (score 2):

If you will only create the `Profile` when you already have a corresponding `User`, you can leave the `user_id` out of the `Profile` factory, and then [use the magic methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#has-many-relationships-using-magic-methods) to create both at the same time.

```php
User::factory()->hasProfiles(1)->create();
```

This will automatically create a profile to match the user.

---

Or, if you do need to create a profile before creating a user, you can define the `user_id` like this [in your factory](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#relationships-within-definition), and a `User` will be created by the `Profile`.

```php
return [
    'user_id' => User::factory(),
    'image' => 'image',
    'bio' => $this->faker->sentence,
];
```

Comment: I like this first way more. So, I just need to call User::factory().... in DatabaseSeeder after calling factory for creating users?

Comment: Currently, I have these factory calls: https://prnt.sc/vmeigb

Answer (score 1):

```
'user_id' => $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,5000),
```

Answer (score 0):

**The best way** is to pass a `user_id` whenever **you need to create** a fake profile record.

in profile factory:

```
return [
        'image' => 'image',
        'bio' => $this->faker->sentence,
...
```

Wherever you need it:

```
Profile::factory()->for(User::create() , user)->create();
```

For more information, you can read this part of the [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#belongs-to-relationships).

Answer (score -1):

```
'user_id' => $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 500)
```

Should be total quantity of your users.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the answer from Salma mehanny